# CTAN package does not appear in TexLive utility

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, ctan

I want to install [this package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie?lang=en) from CTAN, but I can't find it through the TexLive Utility. Why would it not appear, and what can I do about it?

(If it's relevant, I'm using MacTex.)

Comment: I can't see any license statement: that would exclude it from TeX Live.

Comment: It is also stated on the CTAN page that it is not available in TeXLive. The project page mentioned in the STY does not exist anymore. You might want to write the author and ask the maintainer to make sure license information is mentioned in the sources

Comment: The package seems to consist only of one sty. Copy it somewhere where your document can find it.